# Removing/collapsing git history

Tags: git, garbage-collection

My git repository is starting to get a bit too large. On a single SSD, I have a repository and two clones with a lot of binary files that take up an awful lot of space.

Every day, a cron job pushes the master clone to the repository to create a history of changes over a long period of time.

However, anything over a month old isn't really worth keeping anymore. I'd like to be able to remove those old commits to save a lot of space... programatically.

I've seen plenty of examples using `rebase` and `squash`, a couple using `gc`, and some other really funky ones. Most of these require you to manually type in the commit tags you want to remove.

I want to remove all commits older than 30 days from my repository (I suppose I'll have to configure hooks to collapse the history elsewhere too) every month from a bash script.

Comment: I'd say that version control systems aren't designed to not keep the full history. The fact that you can actually do that with git doesn't mean you need git for that.

Comment: True, but I still can't find anything better. Git ticks all the right boxes!

Should I make another post about alternatives to Git for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this. It gets the first commit then initiate rebase. Just remove commits to your liking.

```sh
# Get first commit
git log --format=%H | tail -1 | xargs git rebase -i
```

[**ref**](http://svnpenn.github.com/2012/git/)

Comment: The binary files are essential to the system. It's actually a Minecraft server.